# Vague error: Limit Exceeded

Tags: apex

has anyone ever come across this error:

> Limit Exceeded
>
> You or your organization has exceeded the maximum limit for this
>   feature.

It is *rather* vague, so attempting to find a starting point. Appears on VF page which features Apex. Premise of it is to search up contacts, which you then add to a selection, which are then saved as child records to a master record.

Common theme appears to be saving when there are a multitude of various accounts added to this selection, and a population of them have a one to one checkbox ticked. Tick 9 and it saves fine, tick 10 and it pops that error.

Can't quite figure out why this would happen though.

*edit - redundant code/text red herring removed*

I started enabling and disabling triggers. I found one that was going through and updating a field in the child records with the result of a calculation. Disabling this stopped the error.

However, there was nothing in the code that dealt with the one to one checkbox and that was the tipping point between the field saving or erroring.

I went inside my child object where there is a simple formula:

`IF( One_To_One__c = TRUE, 1,0)`

Removing that and placing a hardcoded number in there also allows the code to run.

It seems that there is an inability for the trigger and this formula to exist. I now need to find a way where they can.

Comment: Have you tried the process with the developer console running? You may see your answer in there. Alternatively try writing some execute anonymous code that uses the limits static methods. see http://docs.database.com/dbcom/en-us/db_apex/apex_System_Limits_static_methods.htm?version=186.0

Comment: Is there an Apex trigger on the PCM_Activity_Attendee__c object?

Comment: There is a trigger, but I'm sure I tried it with it disabled. I'll try Developer Console too.

Comment: Tracked it back to a trigger I have not looked at before. Will go away and have a read of it to find out what it does, when it does it, is it useful and why on earth it is causing a limit to break.

Comment: Appears to be a combination of the trigger and the formula on the object itself (as detailed above now). I somehow have to figure out a way to have these both run.

Be a lot more useful if I was told WHAT limit I was breaking...

Comment: Are you inserting all the contact records in one call?  or multiple?  Perhaps there is a "bulkification" issue in the trigger...

Answer (score 5):

If you run the request that's hitting the error limit with the developer console open, a log of the code that runs is generated. At the end of the huge log is a list of the limits Salesforce has and how close you are to each. Just above that list toward the end of the log will also be the exception thrown when you hit the limit.

Once you have the Developer Console open, Click on Debug -> Switch Perspective -> Log Only (Predefined). That will remove some of the clutter that you don't need right now (Feel free to explore, it can be quite useful).

[image: Developer Console Limit List]

Comment: Too many SOQL queries: 101

I wonder if this is a circular issue? Trigger updates record, formula updates, re-triggers trigger, formula updates...

Comment: Confirmed. Formula updates once I update a field on the child, then rolls up to parent object, I believe this is triggering the trigger on the parent en-masse.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As a series of FOR loops within an IF were causing this problem (they contained some SOQL), I made the IF skip the FOR loops didn't need to do anything.

Considering I don't really have a grasp of Apex, I'm so happy.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Amusingly, I have troubleshot what this is attempting to do and realised that whatever has been designed here is total nonsense, so I could have just done as well to disable the entire thing! Still, learning stuff I suppose...