# Error: your organization has exceeded the request limit for the service you are trying to access

Tags: workflow

A number of users in our org are seeing the above error when trying to edit then save an opportunity. The few articles I've seen on this reference it occurring when you have a high number of workflow rules on Opportunity (which we definitely have) but not much more useful info. Anybody seen this and/or can point me in the direction of a potential fix?

Comment: This link might be helpful -- https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019O7hQAE.

Comment: This link maybe helpful [Vague error: Limit Exceeded](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22025/vague-error-limit-exceeded)